# Linking forms for homology with general coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups

For integral homology groups there is the notion of linking form (http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Linking_form)
$$
Tor(H_{l}(X,\mathbb{Z}))\times Tor(H_{n-l-1}(X,\mathbb{Z}))\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}
$$
for the torsion part of the homology groups. This can be defined by using the Bockstein map associated with the sequence $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Maybe this is a very trivial generalization, but is there an analogous notion for homology groups with coefficients in an arbitrary abelian group $A$? I am looking for something like
$$
Tor(H_{l}(X,A))\times Tor(H_{n-l-1}(X,A^{\vee}))\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}
$$
where $A^{\vee}$ is the dual group. If yes, what is the Bockstein map one should use?

Comment: the codomain will probably changed. a little googling landed me here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06800.pdf

Comment: I am actually interested only in the case in which $A$ is finite, and $A^{\vee}$ is the Pontryagin dual. I thought the co-domain could then be thought as the result of the natural pairing...